# HTML submit only submitting itself

Tags: php, html, forms

first things first, english isn't my native language, so feel free to ask if I am being unclear.

I am currently trying to get a small webpage to work for a college task (and no, I'm not asking you to do my homework, but I currently am stuck and no amount of search has turned up valuable results so far) and it seems like my submit buttons only submit their own values and nothing else.

For example:

I have a form called "list" that has a select element, two buttons and one submit element.

Code:

```
<form id="list" action="process.php" method="post" onsubmit="return order()">

    <select name="cart[]" id="myCart" size="6" multiple>

        [contents of select element]

    </select>

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Delete All" class="custombuttonsmall" onclick="deleteElements()">
        <input type="button" value="Delete Selected" class="custombuttonsmall" onclick="deleteElement()">
        <input type="submit" value="Order" class="custombuttonsmall" name="order">
    </p>

</form>
```

Note: the "order()" function checks if there are options in the select element. If there isn't, the process won't come through.

process.php currently only has two lines,

```
$q = $_POST;
var_dump($q);
```

to test if submitting works.

Result of var_dump:

```
array(1) { ["order"]=> string(5) "Order" }
```

Every other value I'm trying to call (e.g. $q = $_POST['cart']) returns NULL. Basically, my submit button seems to only submit its own value instead of the whole form. And I can't seem to figure out why. It happens for every form I'm trying t submit.

Sorry if this has been asked before or is too specific, but again, I haven't been able to get any progress on this so far.

Thanks in advance,

//EDIT:
Browsers used are Chromium 34.0.x and Firefox 30.0, same results on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only *selected* options in a select element will be submitted.

Based on your `bytton` values, it seems likely that you are dynamically adding and removing options (without actually selecting them) instead of using the browser's native multiple selection UI.

Comment: Yes, you're right, forgot to add this. Options are dynamically added and removed via JavaScript functions.
What's the "native multiple selection UI" if I may ask? And also, would it be possible to submit the values if I declare them "selected" (via JavaScript possibly)?

Comment: The native multiple selection UI is what the browser presents the user with when you have a select multiple. Typically it works by clicking to select one and then Ctrl or Shift clicking to select more.